# Factoring a for in "of" expressions

Tags: grammar, punctuation, parallelism, prepositions

I am wondering if I can factor a word in the following expression:

*According to the definition of A, definition of B, and definition of C, ...*

and write it briefly as

*According to the definition of A, of B, and of C, ...*

or

*According to the definition of A, that of B, and that of C, ...*.

Comment: Another alternative is: *According to the  definition**s** of A, B, and C*.

Comment: Which one is correct or more common?

Answer (score 2):

The most common solution is to say **definitions**, as in

> According to the **definitions** of "child-friendly" in the user manual, the safety sheet, and the online product description, the item is safe for children under three years old.

Comment: This is a different case, in my question, the word "definition" can be distributed over _A_, _B_, and _C_

Comment: @SaraWinslet, please update your post to make your question more specific. Include a complete sentence if possible.